# Not able to call Observer in KVO

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

When I tap on a textfield, I open a `tableview` with a list of names. I navigate to this  tableview using a segue. Once an element is selected from the tableview, I fetch it in my viewcontroller having the textfield using callback...

This is the prepareForSegue function...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "seguedropdown2" {
         
        vc.datacallback = { (message) in
        
        if(message[2] as! Int == 8) {
           self.Smat_Receiver1 = "\(message[0])"
           self.receiver.receiverName1 = self.Smat_Receiver1 // Observer added here. But it's not called
        }
        
        if(message[2] as! Int == 9) {
           self.Smat_Receiver2 = "\(message[0])"
           self.receiver.receiverName2 = self.Smat_Receiver2 //Observer added here. But it's not called
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

And this is how I have setup my Observer

```
var ob:NSKeyValueObservation!
let receiver = Receiver()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

    ob = receiver.observe(\Receiver.receiverName1, options: .new) { person, change in
        print("Receiver 1 is now \(person.receiverName1)")
    }
    ob = receiver.observe(\Receiver.receiverName2, options: .new) { person, change in
        print("Receiver 2 is now \(person.receiverName2)")
    }

}
```

And else where, I have setup `Receiver` like so...

```
@objc class Receiver: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var receiverName1 = String()
    @objc dynamic var receiverName2 = String()
}
```

My issue is, the observer is not getting called whenever, I set a new value.

Comment: Why do you need KVO, how about `willSet/didSet`?

Comment: true...I finally used `willSet/didSet`. But I would like to know why the KVO is not working in this case...

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you code is saving two observation instances to single variable but each of them should be stored separately and it causes invalidation the first of them.

```swift
var ob1:NSKeyValueObservation!
var ob2:NSKeyValueObservation!
...
ob1 = receiver.observe(\.receiverName1, options: .new) { person, change in
...
}
ob2 = receiver.observe(\.receiverName2, options: .new) { person, change in
...
}
```